# Box2d Degrees are flipped

Tags: ios, box2d

I have a B2Body which I am setting it's velocity. I am using Box2d And noticed that the degrees are flipped. In other words, I essentially have a backwards protractor (one that starts at zero from the right instead of the left). Can anyone give me an algorithm to make it so that it starts at zero from the left?

NOTE: I tried angle += 180; However now when I have 90 as the angle, It goes down instead of up but 180 and 0 work fine.

Comment: this is the standard way rotation is defined. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unit_circle.svg

Comment: just use (180 - angle) instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used iforce2d's suggestion, worked with a couple of modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply the angle by -1.